# Using Swagger-Jersey-JAXRS module and JPA annotated Entities

Tags: jpa, swagger

I'm trying to use the Swagger-Jersey-JAXRS module in order to document a very simple RESTful data service.

Following the instructions at the "Java JAXRS Quickstart": https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-core/wiki/Java-JAXRS-Quickstart, I have annotated my POJO with

```
@XmlElement(name = "Address")
@ApiModelProperty(value = "The Provider Address")
private String address;
```

The above code lives in a class named Provider witch is annotated as a JPA @Entity.

When using swagger-ui to visualize the REST API the GET operation that returns the 'Provider' entity does not show the swagger 'value' and the provided name at the @XmlElement like this:

```
Provider {
    address (string, optional),
    ...
}
```

The Java method used to return a list of Providers is like this:

```
@GET
@Path("/")
@Produces( { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@ApiOperation(value = "Find Providers for ....", notes = "Get all the Providers for the ... filtered by type.",response = Provider.class, responseContainer = "List")
public List<Provider> listProviders(@ApiParam(value = "The id to use", required = true)
    @QueryParam("id")
    String id) {
   ...
}
```

If I remove the JPA annotation from the Provider class, then everything works as expected. My understanding is that the JPA annotation is killing swagger.

Is this a known feature/limitation/bug on swagger that I have missed in my search? Or is it a concept that I have not understood.

Thanks

Comment: FWIW: I see the same. You say "JPA" annotation, I think you mean "JAXB". I have different annotations (@XmlRootElement) but the result is the same